# While using fgetl command to get a string from keyboard, after giving the input the 'Enter' key has to be pressed two times

Tags: octave

While using the `fgetl` command to get a string from the keyboard, after giving the input the 'Enter' key has to be pressed two times. Why is this?

The code is shown below

```
printf("Enter your name : ");
name = fgetl(stdin);
printf("Your Name  is %s\n", name)
```

Comment: how are you running the code above? trying to run your code either from an m file script or function or direct in the interpreter I get the error "error: fgetl: unable to read from stdin while running interactively"

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess, this is a side effect of the fact that `fgetl` expects a 'proper' file. It is not designed for interactive use.

As such, it tries to figure out if the next line is the end of file or an empty line, to process the previous newline appropriately. (you can imagine e.g. if a file run into the EOF character before a newline, this would have to be handled specially). Or it may even relate to trying to deal appropriately with line terminators between operating systems ...

In any case, if what you're after is interactive input specifically, you should probably just use the `input` command instead.